# New Orleans style Exterior Wood Shutters

Tags: joinery, wood-movement, water-protection, outdoor, panel

What process would you go through to create this style of shutters, with the expectation that they're built for long-life? Specifically, I'm interested in how the back panel is put together: glue or no glue? Tongue and groove? And how the frame and moulding would be attached to the back panel. Looks to basically be a jazzed up version of a board-and-batten shutter.

[image: Fullsized door shutters]

Comment: Do you have to use traditional rail and style construction methods? If you can live with something that looks similar, you could construct this shutter from marine grade plywood. That would last a long time, and probably be easier to make.

Comment: I'm not married to raw wood, and am practical. That said, because of how wet and humid New Orleans is, and because they get tropical storms and hurricanes, I figured there's probably some solid design theory behind this style.

Comment: *"I figured there's probably some solid design theory behind this style."* I figure the idea is the outside layer is built for utility (sheds water better) and the inside layer, which you'd tend to see more, is built to be more attractive using another established method to allow for movement in solid wood. I can only guess how traditionally the two layers were joined together, possibly they simply nailed the outer to the inner — nailed construction can allow for a surprising amount of relative movement.

Comment: I assumed they were nailed together as well. I looked up how to make board-and-batten shutters, but there seems to be some disagreement. For example, a "This Old House" tutorial suggests gluing the horizontal piece, but that would not allow the panel to move. My assumption is that (historically) there's supposed to be a small gap between each board, and they were probably held together with pegs on center. Here they apparently joined the panel with tongue and groove and then nailed the "pretty" frame to one side, with nails centered on the panels boards. Just curious what others thought.

Comment: I found this on the website of a shutter builder in Baton Rouge: 

"By using rot resistant wood and techniques very similar to those of the craftsmen who built the shutters of the French Quarter...Our standard product uses 1- 1/16" thick rails and stiles which are assembled with a mortise and tendon joint. For greater strength required of larger shutters or personal taste, we can easily build from 1- 3/8ths rails and stiles. Slat size can vary in size to include 2", 2- 1/4", 2- 1/2" & 3- 1/2"..."  (http://www.highlandmillworks.com/shutters.html) I guess the outside is tongue & groove planks?

Comment: I would just make the thing using good basic joinery (tongue-and-groove, dowels, glue, screws, whatever floats your boat) and follow through with the last and in my opinion most important detail that no one has mentioned: the paint.  To me, the paint makes wood movement and wood rot non-issues, so just build it and keep the paint fresh, no worries.  No paint?  That's a different story, but the OP didn't suggest such a design constraint.